# How can I retrieve the netmask attribute from OHAI?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to be able to grab the netmask for an instance's interface when bootstrapping the instance. After running ohai on the instance, I have the following output that will supply the netmask:

```
 "network": {
    "interfaces": {
      "lo": {
        "mtu": "65536",
        "flags": [
          "LOOPBACK",
          "UP",
          "LOWER_UP"
        ],
        "encapsulation": "Loopback",
        "addresses": {
          "127.0.0.1": {
            "family": "inet",
            "prefixlen": "8",
            "netmask": "255.0.0.0",
            "scope": "Node"
          }
        },
        "state": "unknown"
      },
      "ens5": {
        "type": "ens",
        "number": "5",
        "mtu": "9001",
        "flags": [
          "BROADCAST",
          "MULTICAST",
          "UP",
          "LOWER_UP"
        ],
        "encapsulation": "Ethernet",
        "addresses": {
          "0E:D6:03:1B:8D:42": {
            "family": "lladdr"
          },
          "10.191.196.213": {
            "family": "inet",
            "prefixlen": "24",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
             "broadcast": "10.191.196.255",
            "scope": "Global"
          }
         },...
```

I'm not getting the correct syntax, but I have found that I can get the IP address with this:

```
node[:network][:interfaces][:eth0][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first
```

Using this however, will not get the netmask:

```
node[:network][:interfaces][:ens192][:addresses][:netmask]
```

Any ideas on the correct ruby to get this value?

*Edit - using:

```
node["network"]["interfaces"]["ens192"]["addresses"].values.find { |i| i["family"] == "inet" }["netmask"]
```

I get this error:

```
    [2018-04-24T17:06:45-04:00] ERROR:

   Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) on line #9:
     7: DNS2=<%= node['dns_dtbg']['dns_servers_dtbg'][1] %>
     8: PEERDNS=no
     9: NETMASK=<%= node["network"]["interfaces"]["ens192"]["addresses"].values.find { |i| i["family"] == "inet" }["netmask"] %>
    10: TYPE=Ethernet
```

Comment: That output is not valid Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node[:network][:interfaces][:ens5][:addresses].detect do |k,v|
  v[:family]=='inet'
end.last[:netmask]
```

You could find out it by pasting your json to pry or irb, and check the result every time after adding another nested key fetch. Also, you can probably improve this answer by using `Hash#dig`.

Comment: This worked thanks! Not clear on your steps to test with Pry or IRB however... can you link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
node["network"]["interfaces"]["ens192"]["addresses"].values.find { |i| i["family"] == "inet" }["netmask"]
```

You should also check if you are not getting any empty Mash along the road.

Comment: 7: DNS2=<%= node['dns_dtbg']['dns_servers_dtbg'][1] %>
         8: PEERDNS=no
         9: NETMASK=<%= node["network"]["interfaces"]["ens192"]["addresses"].values.find { |i| i["family"] == "inet" }["netmask"] %>
        10: TYPE=Ethernet

Comment: [2018-04-24T17:06:45-04:00] ERROR:

       Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) on line #9:

Comment: Please use proper code formatting. Are you sure it is `ens192`? In you example it was `ens5`. Also as I wrote, you should check if any previous mash is not empty / nil (for example `["network"]["interfaces"]["ens192"]` may be nil).

Comment: I previously added the reply output above to the original question. I am trouble shooting on different machines... one ens192, one ens5 and one eth0. The mash is not empty.